# Apex Getter Setter

Tags: apex

```
 @RemoteAction
public static void saveActivitySettings(){

    public String selectedStage {get;set;}
    public Boolean isLeadConverted {get;set;}

}
```

Why it is throwing following error for getter setter :

> Compile Error: expecting a semi-colon, found '{'

Comment: Is `isLeadConverted` referred any where in this method?

Answer (score 3):

You can't declare global variable inside a method. Move the `public String selectedStage {get;set;}`, `public Boolean isLeadConverted {get;set;}` to class level.

```
public class VFRemoteTestingPage {
    public String selectedStage {get;set;}
    public Boolean isLeadConverted {get;set;}

    @RemoteAction
    public static void saveActivitySettings(){
        //Your logic
    }
}
```

Comment: now its throwing : Variable does not exist: isLeadConverted

Comment: It wont throw any error if you try to save the above class

Comment: @user40665 If possible can you please post the entire class code.

Comment: I have changed the variables to static.. now its ok